# Attempted to read or write protected memory. while try to receive frame in image variable

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." getting this error when i am trying to store the frame by calling **RetrieveBgrFrame()** method.
Actually i am trying to open a medial file and when ImageGrabbed event got file try to store it in image variable for further procesing 
File Type Dummy.avi
Here is my Code:

```
public partial class CameraCapture : Form
{
  private Capture _capture = null;
  private bool _captureInProgress;


  public CameraCapture()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     try
     {
        _capture = new Capture(@"D:\imageprocessing\CapturedImages\CameraSample-1.avi");
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
     }
     catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
     }
  }

  private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
  {
     **Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();**
     *//Here is the Error*        

     Image<Gray, Byte> grayFrame = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
     Image<Gray, Byte> smallGrayFrame = grayFrame.PyrDown();
     Image<Gray, Byte> smoothedGrayFrame = smallGrayFrame.PyrUp();
     Image<Gray, Byte> cannyFrame = smoothedGrayFrame.Canny(100, 60);

     captureImageBox.Image = frame;
     grayscaleImageBox.Image = grayFrame;
     smoothedGrayscaleImageBox.Image = smoothedGrayFrame;
     cannyImageBox.Image = cannyFrame;
  }

  private void captureButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (_capture != null)
     {
        if (_captureInProgress)
        {  //stop the capture
           captureButton.Text = "Start Capture";
           _capture.Pause();
        }
        else
        {
           //start the capture
           captureButton.Text = "Stop";
           _capture.Start();
        }

        _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
     }
  }

  private void ReleaseData()
  {
     if (_capture != null)
        _capture.Dispose();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a `Grab()` before you use the `RetrieveBgrFrame` (see IntelliSense documentation of the function). There is a simpler way to do it, by using the `QueryFrame()` function.

Here is the minimal code to capture video in EmguCV:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
...

ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera captue
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
   viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); //draw the image obtained from camera
});
viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
```

You can find this example on the official [EmguCV website](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.My problem is resolved, there was some issue with the .avi file.

Comment: Can you please share with the community what you did to fix it? You can even accept your own answer to show everyone what to do with this problem.